# Sum of prime numbers related to Euler's totient function

Tags: totient-function

Let *p* be a prime number. Decide $$\sum_{k=0}^n \phi(p^k)$$

I have had difficulties with how to deal with the problem. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Just exploit $\phi(p^k)=p^k-p^{k-1}$. Your sum is a telescopic one.

Comment: Bearing in mind that $\phi(p^0)=\phi(1)=1$, not $1-\frac{1}{p}$